# How to line up the top of two centered divs in a flex container?

Tags: css, flexbox

Here is an example of my code :

```css
.flex-container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #ffeeee
}

#item1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#item2 {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div id="item1"></div>
  <div id="item2"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vL508wax/

I want the blue square to be centered and the top of the red square to be flush with the top of the blue square.

I know I can do this with `margin-top` for example but I don't think that's a good way to go. Can I do this with flexbox directly ?

Comment: you said *I want the blue square to be centered*. doesn't look centred in the below answer to me. Can you make the question clear, maybe you want both of them centred while having the red to the top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about your use case nor have I done enough testing with this, But if there will always be 2 elements, you can make use of `flex wrap` alongside `align-content: center;`

```css
.flex-container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #ffeeee
}

#item1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#item2 {
  width: 120px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div id="item1"></div>
  <div id="item2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I always forget about the `align-content`, good answer!

Answer (score 3):

A CSS grid solution since it would be difficult with flexbox:

```css
.flex-container{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  display:grid;
  grid-auto-flow:column; /* side by side */
  grid-template-rows:100px; /* the blue height here */
  /* center everything*/
  align-content:center;
  justify-content:center;
  /**/
  background: 
    linear-gradient(green 0 0) center/100% 1px no-repeat,
    #ffeeee
}

#item1{
  width:100px;
  height:100%;
  background-color:blue;
}

#item2{
  width:120px;
  height:120px;
  background-color:red;
  transition:1s all;
}
#item2:hover {
  height:160px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div id="item1">
  
  </div>
  <div id="item2">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would seem that Grid would be a more efficient solution. But with `align-content`, it appears that flex works just fine.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin the question said *blue need to be centred* **and** *red to be on the top* So for me we need to first center the blue then we adjust the red to its top (probably not what the OP meant at the end)

Comment: Agreed that precise centering as requested was not achieved in the flex answer.